# How can I map each field of an event to a separate column when creating a table using Flink Table API from a data-stream of Confluent Avro?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-table-api

How to create table using Table Api in flink for modelling

I am working on creating a table using Table API from the data-stream of confluent-avro (from kafka topic). I am trying using the below code ( Flink version is 1.17) and it is creating table in such a way that resultTable column contains the complete json in one column of table. Can someone please help me in how to create table in such a way that each field of event is mapped to one column in the table.

```
DataStream<GenericRecord> dataStream = ...;

StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
Table attribution = tableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStream);

tableEnv.createTemporaryView("attribution", attribution);
Table resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT f0 FROM attribution");
tableEnv.createTemporaryView("resultTable", resultTable);
tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT `field_name` from resultTable").execute().collect().forEachRemaining(System.out::println); // Throwing Exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variant of `fromDataStream` that takes a Schema as the second argument. Here's an example I copied from the documentation:

```java
Table table =
    tableEnv.fromDataStream(
        dataStream,
        Schema.newBuilder()
            .column("event_time", "TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)")
            .column("name", "STRING")
            .column("score", "INT")
            .watermark("event_time", "SOURCE_WATERMARK()")
            .build());
```

`SOURCE_WATERMARK()` is for cases where the DataStream being converted to a Table already has suitable watermarks.

Comment: I tried the other variant of fromDataStream but i am getting an exception :

org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to find a field named 'visit_id' in the physical data type derived from the given type information for schema declaration. Make sure that the type information is not a generic raw type. Currently available fields are: [f0]

Code:
tableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStream, Schema.newBuilder().column("field_name", "STRING").build());

The output is generating RAW format with column name as f0. Could you please let me know where did i went wrong.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. Perhaps if you share enough to reproduce the problem it will be easier to see what's the problem is.